# Swift generic type defined by method context

Tags: swift, generics

Is there a name for a pattern where the type is inferred by the context of the result type?

Eg in this example what language could i use to document the `foo` method and explain that a type needs to be defined for the method to work?

```
protocol FooType {
   init()
}

func foo<T: FooType>() -> T {
    return T()
}

struct Bar: FooType {
    init() {
        print("bar")
    }
}


let bar: Bar = foo()
// works returns instance of Bar

let fooType = foo()
// fails because foo doesn't know what type to use
```

Comment: Code comments aren't meant to explain the "how" or the "what" of code. It explains the "why". You don't have to explain Swift to the swift programmers who read your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to document this!

Everyone that writes code in Swift knows that to call a generic function, all its type parameters must be inferred and cannot be spoon-fed like this:

```
foo<Bar>()
```

People will see `foo` and say, "Oh I need the compiler to infer the type for this generic parameter." They will understand what this means.

Comment: +1 right, and I guess if they don't, at least the complier will give a useful message to guide them the right direction.